# how browser determine which element to give focus on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I want to know, which element will be set as active element when page completes loading.

I tried to look into specification at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-document-activeelement, but I am not able to find a how browser set active element after loading page.

And I haven't programmatically set focus to any of element.

One way to track, i found is

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("focus",_dom_trackActiveElement,true);
  document.addEventListener("blur",_dom_trackActiveElementLost,true);
}
```

Comment: mostly its first input element ...

Comment: Well, what kind of results you've got when using the listeners?

Answer (score 0):

try like this , it will give you focus element

```
$(":focus").each(function() {
    alert("Focused Element = "+ this.id );
});
```

or can use this, which gives you focused element

```
$( document.activeElement )
```